# Returning integer values conditionally in numberOfRowsInSection function of tableView

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

If label `title` contains value from `stadiumName`, then `numberOfRowsInSection` function will return a value `first!.count`.

If label `title` contains value from `countryName`, then `numberOfRowsInSection` function will return a value of `3`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        let pfile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "scheduling", ofType: "plist")

        let indexes = defaults.integer(forKey: "index")
        let indexes2 = defaults.integer(forKey: "index2")

        let stadiumName = stadia[indexes]
        let countryName = country[indexes2]

        let arrays = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: pfile!)

        let first = arrays?.value(forKey: stadia[indexes]) as? [[String]]

        if (titles.text?.contains(stadiumName))!{

            let returning = first!.count

            return returning
        }
        if (titles.text?.contains(countryName))!{

            let returning = 3

            return returning
        }

    }
```

However, I am faced with this error message: `Missing return in a function expected to return 'Int'`

What can I do to ensure I can return a value conditionally without this error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's saying that your "if" statements aren't exhaustive and there are scenarios where the end of the function will be reached without returning a value.  The simple solution is to just add "return 0" at the end of the function.

Comment: Terrific. Thank you. That worked.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 `if` statements that both could not be satisfied. Try this:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        let pfile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "scheduling", ofType: "plist")

        let indexes = defaults.integer(forKey: "index")
        let indexes2 = defaults.integer(forKey: "index2")

        let stadiumName = stadia[indexes]
        let countryName = country[indexes2]

        let arrays = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: pfile!)

        let first = arrays?.value(forKey: stadia[indexes]) as? [[String]]

        if (titles.text?.contains(stadiumName))!{

            let returning = first!.count

            return returning
        }
        else if (titles.text?.contains(countryName))!{

            let returning = 3

            return returning
        } else {
            return 0
        }


    }
```

Comment: There are a lot of crash operators in this code. Not good.